# 18.04 LTS - can't access CD drive: "special device /dev/sr0 does not exist"

Tags: 18.04, mount, dvd

First time posting here - but I've been trawling around here, there and everywhere for an answer to this problem for almost a week.
I need help to get my system to recognize my CD writer.

- I installed 18.04 LTS on a HP microserver, from usb, about 4 weeks ago. Looking at /var/log, that was the only time my CD/DVD writer was seen.
- BIOS shows it (very briefly) as ATAPI CD_ROM... I think it's attached as primary-slave.
- The drive works - I can start to boot the machine using the CDROM drive and a very old Ubuntu CD I had in a cupboard.
- under /dev/ there are no sr[0,1,2] devices, nor are there any hd[a,b,c,etc] devices.

I've tried any number of mount options - but the fact is that no CD device is ever locatable -I always end up with the "special device [ e.g. /dev/sr0] does not exist" message.

I've started to think I need to modify the kernel - but that's a bit beyond my usual level of tinkering!

Can I use an installation USB to fix this while not overwriting my existing apps (web server, KVMs...)?

The reason this is a problem now is that I simply didn't know the drive was unavailable, until I wanted to try and rip a CD earlier in the week.

Comment: Look through the entire output of `sudo lshw`. Is it listed at all?

Comment: No - there are entries for... a SATA controller, various USB controllers, pci bridges,SCSI 0 (hard disk1), SCSI 1 (hard disk 2) and various network devices. But nothing like CD or DVD or 'optical' or ...

Comment: More info - I've tried all sort of options that I've read on similar threads to this, but to no avail. (e.g. I'd already been down the 'lshw' route, a number of times), but I'm hoping that a fresh perspective from someone else will illuminate this for me.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've solved my own problem - though I'm not at all sure how or why.

Trying to fix an issue copying music files where some were not copied because file or folder names included foreign or accented characters, I tried adding an ‘iocharset’ parameter to the CIFS mount option in /etc/fstab :

`//Ext-dd/iTunes /media/iTunes cifs vers=1.0,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=1000,gid=1000,nofail 0 0`

– but that failed to mount, apparently because a very large linux library needed to be installed:

`sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends linux-image-extra-virtual`

(NB the –no-install-recommends option had no apparent effect.)
The process included accepting or rejecting an updated kernel - I accepted, as I had suspected the current kernel wasn't right.
Once that was installed, and the system was rebooted, not only were the folders apparently mounted correctly, and the encoding seems to work – but the DVD player is back!